# Are there legal reasons to maintain addresses for my clients?

Tags: international, business

If I'm opening a hosting company and would there be any legal reason or requirement to obtain the home or business addresses of my clients?

Comment: In what country? Also, if not having an address for the client could open you up for lawsuits that you could otherwise redirect to them, would you consider that "required to have address?"

Comment: @cpast, this is in UK, but i'm planning on doing this worldwide, and no i wouldn't count that as requirement, unless it's stated in the laws somewhere.

Comment: Please hire an attorney to advise you.

Comment: @Mowzer, ok then

Comment: I believe that an address is a mandatory part of an invoice in Germany, but I don't know under which circumstances you're required to create an invoice.

Comment: Arguably, in the UK you are legally obliged to only hold that information about a customer which is necessary for performing the service.   You may need a billing address to be able to take card payments, but I don't think you need to store that once the payment is verified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you are under no obligation to keep address records - at least, I wasn't able to find any laws that impose a general obligation on businesses.

However, there may be laws that impose such requirements on certain types of businesses - for example, financial institutions are required to verify the identity of their customers, and address records are almost certainly part of the process for doing so.

Similarly, if you are professionally insured (for instance, in the legal sector), you may be contractually required to complete an identity check, which maintaining address records may form part of. **Of course, being a hosting company, this might not apply to you**, though if you have insurance, you should probably check the terms, or ask them for information on this matter.

Lastly, although you may have dismissed this as a legal reason to do so, you may wish to maintain address records in order to, if the need arises, verify the identity of a customer who might bring a claim against you, or to dispute the identity of a party attempting to do so - the less information you have, the harder it would be for you to verify that they are, in fact, a customer, and this *could* result in unwarranted judgements against you.

Of course, because you're trading internationally, it's a bit difficult to ensure that no laws, anywhere, require this of you - some countries have laws with extraterritorial effect.